# Preventing RSS feed scraping?

Tags: rss, screen-scraping

On a Wordpress site, I have both a normal blog that I want Google to detect and an RSS feed for outgoing links to other sites. I don't need/want bots to get at this other RSS feed nor do I want people to be able to get the link for their own use.

I've disabled RSS for the main blog successfully but am not sure how to encrypt/protect/hide the RSS link for this additional feed.

I'm not sure how Facebook runs a newsfeed without RSS but however they do it is probably beyond my means/experience to replicate.

Where these are just outgoing links, I don't think copyright notices in the feed will do much. Maybe there is a way to output the links automatically through a means other than RSS?

Comment: I assume you do NOT want to disable Wordpress creating the RSS feeds altogether, right? If in fact you want to get rid of the RSS, then I guess your title needs some change. (I don't understand "an RSS feed for outgoing links to other sites", but it could very well be my knowledge about RSS usage scenarios, or Wordpress, that fails me here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic answer to this is to use a method of getting the feed entries in a manner other than using the actual RSS like outputting JSON, going through the API, etc.

It will help prevent scraping though not completely.

Answer (score 0):

Use Robots.Text [www.robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org) to prevent google from following the link.  All self respecting robots should follow the directives in the robots.txt file.  This file needs to go in the root of your sit.

Comment: Beware that Google Reader will access any feed if someone subscribes to it. FeedFetcher, the robot that indexes feeds for Reader does not use robots.txt. See http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html#robots for their explanation.